# Java generics: getting rid unchecked cast warning (case described inside)

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, casting, type-erasure

*Please forgive the bad naming, the problem described below is a very crude simplification and alteration of real code*

I have the following types defined:

```
interface Bundle {
  // omitted
}
```

```
interface Content<T extends Bundle> {
  void useBundle(T bundle);
  Class<? extends T> getSupportedBundleClass();
  // omitted
}
```

```
class Service<T extends Bundle> {
  private final T bundle;
  
  public Collection<Content<? super T>> someMethod(Collection<Object> allContents) {
    // omitted
  }  
}
```

The purpose of **someMethod** in **Service** is to filter such instances of **Content** whose supported bundle class is either the same as the **bundle**'s class or higher up the hierarchy.

For example:

Given the hierarchy of **Bundle**...

```
interface Bundle {}
interface A extends Bundle {}
class B implements A {}
```

... and this set-up, ...

```
Content<Bundle> contentBundle = // omitted
Content<A> contentA = // omitted
Content<B> contentB = // omitted

Service<Bundle> serviceBundle = // omitted
Service<A> serviceA = // omitted
Service<B> serviceB = // omitted

List<Object> allContents = List.of(contentBundle, contentA, contentB);
```

... the following is true:

```
serviceBundle.someMethod(allContents) => [contentBundle]
serviceA.someMethod(allContents) => [contentBundle, contentA]
serviceB.someMethod(allContents) => [contentBundle, contentA, contentB]
```

Here is how **someMethod** is implemented (with the helper method to do the casting and resolve the wildcard):

```
public Collection<Content<? super T>> someMethod(Collection<Object> allContents) {
  return allContents.stream()
    .map(obj -> obj instanceof Content ? (Content<? extends Bundle>) obj : null)   // cast #1
    .filter(Objects:nonNull)
    .map(this::castOrNull)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private <U extends Bundle> Content<? super T> castOrNull(Content<U> content) {
  return content.getSupportedBundleClass().isInstance(bundle) ? (Content<? super T>) content : null;   // cast #2
}
```

My reasoning in the **castOrNull** method is that if the **bundle** in the **Service** class is an instance of the **supported bundle class** of the provided **Content** instance, then the provided **Content**'s type parameter is a supertype of**T** (**bundle**'s type).

**someMethod** works correctly, as expected (described in the example above). However, I get the unchecked cast warning `Content<U>` to `Content<? super T>` on the line with the comment ***// cast #2*** (the line with ***// cast #1*** is fine). Is there any way to eliminate the warning (apart from, of course, suppressing it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This unchecked cast is unavoidable. You are casting something that doesn't involve a type variable to something that does. To check the validity of this cast, the JVM would need to know what type the type variable `T` holds. It unfortunately doesn't. No matter which intermediate types you cast the `Object` to, you are going to introduce the type variable `T` at some point, and that is when the runtime cannot check the validity of the cast, and the cast would be marked as an unchecked cast - the runtime won't do anything about this cast, and it might be possible that this is actually invalid, and everything will blow up later down the line.

Of course, you can introduce your own checks, such as

```
content.getSupportedBundleClass().isInstance(bundle)
```

But note that this is very different from the check that the JVM *would have done*, for checking the validity for `(Content<? super T>) content`, had the type of `T` been available at runtime. In particular, your check depends on implementers of `Content` implementing `getSupportedBundleClass` correctly, returning the enclosing class, and not some subclass of the enclosing class:

```
class ContentBundle implements Content<Bundle> {
    @Override
    public void useBundle(Bundle bundle) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Bundle> getSupportedBundleClass() {
        return B.class;
    }
}
```

This wouldn't be a problem if `getSupportedBundleClass` returned `Class<T>` instead.

I don't know how the field `bundle` gets initialised so I don't know whether this could happen or not, but your check also depends on `Service.bundle` always being an instance of `T`, and not a subclass of `T`. If `serviceBundle.bundle` actually stores an instance of `B`, then `serviceBundle.someMethod(allContents)` would include all 3 contents.

I'd suggest that you use a `Class<T>` to store the type information:

```
private final Class<T> bundleType;
public Service(Class<T> bundleType) {
    this.bundleType = bundleType;
}
```

and use `isAssignableFrom` rather than `isInstance`.

If you think your own checks suffices (for example, if you are sure that everyone would implement `getSupportedBundleClass` in the expected way), then *you* are doing the job of checking the cast, and you should not worry about the JVM not being able to check it. It is fine to suppress it.

In most situations, the solution to the JVM not being to check a cast is to just check it yourself :)

Comment: thank you for such a detailed break-down! The point on Class<T> over Class<? extends T> is taken, I'll definitely introduce that adjustment. As for isAssignableFrom over isInstance, this is how it already is implemented in the real code, I just used isInstance for simplification. Once again many thanks!