# How to safely cast Lazy<*> to specific KClass<T> (Lazy<T>)?

Tags: kotlin, casting, lazy-initialization

I need to get a fabric from fabric collection that will build a `Lazy<T>` instance, my method is below:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") // Dirty hack
override fun <T : Any> resolveLazy(tag: String, clazz: KClass<out T>): Lazy<T> {
    val fabric = fabrics[tag] ?: throw NeutrinoException("The `$tag` not found") // Get ILazyFabric
    if (fabric !is ILazyFabric<*>) { // Ensure if the fabric is really ILazyFabric
        throw NeutrinoException("Can't resolve `$tag` tag: the object is not lazy")
    }
    val obj = fabric.buildOrGet() // Get `Lazy<S>` object
    return obj as Lazy<T> // Need to safely cast our Lazy<S> object to Lazy<T>
    // And catch an exception if it's impossible
}
```

How to implement this method safely? Not to use `@Suppress` and throw a custom exception on fail.

**P.S.** I can't use `reified`.

**UPD:**
Thanks @Sweeper for the comment below, finally I've come to the next solution:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
override fun <T : Any> resolveLazy(tag: String, clazz: KClass<out T>): Lazy<T> {
    val fabric = fabrics[tag] ?: throw NeutrinoException("The `$tag` not found")
    if (fabric !is ILazyFabric<*>) {
        throw NeutrinoException("Can't resolve `$tag` tag: the object is not lazy")
    }
    val obj = fabric.buildOrGet()
    val castedObj = obj as? Lazy<T>
    if (castedObj == null) {
        val objType = obj::class.qualifiedName!!
        val tType = clazz.qualifiedName!!
        throw NeutrinoException(
            "Can't resolve `$tag` tag: `Lazy<$objType>` can't be casted to `Lazy<$tType>`"
        )
    }
    return castedObj
}
```

Comment: `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` isn't a "dirty hack" per se. Suppose you have ensured that ***if `fabrics[tag]` exists and is lazy, then `fabrics[tag].buildOrGet()` must be `Lazy<T>`***, then casting to `Lazy<T>` is perfectly safe. The runtime can't ensure this for you, which is what the "unchecked cast" warning is telling you. You'd just have to check it yourself via other means, and then suppress the warning. I can't really tell you how to do this, without knowing what `fabrics` is and where its contents come from though.

Comment: @Sweeper, thank you for the explanation! I think I will leave this question, maybe it will be useful for someone else. Post yo comment as an answer, plz, to I could accept it

Comment: I've already posted a very similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058636/java-generics-getting-rid-unchecked-cast-warning-case-described-inside/72059338#72059338), though that is about Java, the same principles apply.

Comment: FYI, suppressing the unchecked cast warning is used in several places in the standard library, where manual checks have been done so it’s safe.